# Alphabet I: Prove it!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, language

The sentence below is out of alphabetical order, but can you prove it? As always, good luck!

> All because blue cheese fell happily.

---

### Hints

The language tag is used to denote that the puzzle has something to do with language in particular, whether it's a foreign language, or just a property of a specific language.

> The quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog.

The answer is based around the English language.

> Welcome to word class.

Comment: I Didn't understand the question. What do you mean by alphabetical order

Comment: @Tojrah The language and lateral thinking tags are hints on how to solve this enigmatic puzzle. Best of luck!

Comment: Are we working with the text as we see it?  No invisible characters or non-standard character encodings?

Comment: @MichaelMaggs I’ll be posting a hint later today to try and help out. I can tell you that there are no invisible characters, and no special encodings.

Comment: Is the comma after the word 'fox' in the hint significant? I hope it's not something like rot13("oyhr purrfr" fubhyq or vaqrkrq haqre "purrfr, oyhr".) Another hint now, maybe?

Comment: Hi, could you update, please?

Answer (score 4):

They are English words but out of alphabetical order in:

> the Kiowa language, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) is:
>  A, AU, E, I, O, U, B, F, P, V, D, J, T, TH, G, C, K, Q, CH, X, S, Z, L, Y, W, H, M, N

Answer (score 2):

A second try, in case you didn't like the first one:

> *Almost* all of the letters in the quoted sentence can be found within the phrase "*alphabetical order, but can you prove it. As always, good luck*".  The exception is the letter f, which perhaps comes from the word "of".

Answer (score 1):

The words of the sentence aren't ordered alphabetically, because

> in Czech or Slovak alphabets, `CH` (cheese) stands after `H` (hapilly):
>
>   See: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, CH, I, J, K ...